# Nuget package manager not restoring packages in visual studio 2019

Tags: windows-10, nuget, visual-studio-2019

There is a strange problem going on in all of my office pcs. We are unable to access nuget.org and also we are unable to use the nuget package manager in visual studio. An error occured.. Need help in this issue..

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/deprecating-tls-1-0-and-1-1-on-nuget-org/

Comment: Can you share the detailed error log with us? Can you open the nuget package manager or it did not show up? Please update your issue to share more info about your problem.

Comment: Could you please provide any screenshots about the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and feel very glad that you did great job to fix your issue. Since you have a workaround of your issue, `I suggest you could add your answer and then mark it so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues`. Anyway, have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

> Nuget package manager not restoring packages in visual studio 2019

Please try the following steps to troubleshoot your issue:

**Suggestion**

**1)** please try to enter `https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/` on website and check if it can return any value and **make sure that your Internet is ok.**

- try to turn off firewall, any anti-virus software

**2)** disable any third party vs extensions under menu **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** to eliminate interference from extensions.

**3)** close VS, delete `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config` file, and then restart VS to regenerate the global `nuget.config` file.

**4)** or you could try to use this path `http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/` as `nuget.org`.

**5)** please run

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol-bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

under **Package Manager Console**(under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**)

**6)** try to create a new project in vs to test whether the issue still persists.

**Besides**, if I misunderstand your issue or if I miss some detailed info, please feel free to let us know which will helps us troubleshoot the issue quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. It feels great when someone is out there in the community to help.. Actually ive been struggling with this issue on the last saturday. It had been working fine, suddenly the nuget manager failed to download new packages. after a long time, i came to know that the problem was with our office modem. besides that in my pc the nuget still failed to work since i did some workaround from git and vs-forum to get the nuget working before i actually knew the real issue. Today, i reverted all the workaround back to original manually.. now the nuget is working in other networks

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and feel very glad that you did great job to fix your issue. Since you have a workaround of your issue, `I suggest you could add your answer and then mark it` so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues. Anyway, have a nice day!

Comment: I just want to thank you SO MUCH. Step 5 solved my issue. And for those who might be in the same boat my problems started after I made a repair on my visual studio, maybe that changed the tls?