# Visual Studio can't resolve Nuget dependencies after reinstalling operating system

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package-restore

I recently reinstalled my Windows 10 OS, and now Nuget packages are "not compatible". After an explanation, I will be asking, how do I resolve this problem.

**Lead up**

Due to an unrelated problem, I had to reinstall my operating system. In the course of that, I reinstalled Visual Studio 2019. I cloned my repository (https://github.com/PaulSchrum/CogoDN), then opened it locally with VS.

Now when I build, I get several Nuget errors and warnings. These Nuget dependencies have been present in my code since December 2019, and never caused me a problem until this month (July 2020) associated with the reinstallation of VS.

**Question: How do I resolve this problem?**

Other Details

I am targeting .Net Core 3.1, but it happens no matter which version of .Net Core I target.

The main error seems to be of the pattern:

`NU1202 Package System.Drawing.Common 4.5.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1).`

This is happening for System.Drawing.Common, netDxf.netstandard, and packages necessary for Microsoft Tests. Specifically, it can't recognize `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;` (namespace 'VisualStudio' does not exist), and every attribute ([TestClass], [TestMethod]) now is a syntax error.

**What have I already tried**

Various combinations of reestablishing the Nuget packages. This includes at least twice clearing the Nuget cache and installing the dependencies again. I also followed the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63108317/1339950 (Item 3) Close VS, Delete global NuGet.config, start VS and let it rebuild Nuget.config.

None of these work.

One last note: I have tried so many things and got into various different states of not working that my description may have inadvertently conflated a few details.

Comment: I cloned your project and was able to build it without issues. I would recommend reinstalling .Net Core SDK (uninstall all versions and install only latest) and installing latest version of Nuget.

Answer (score 1):

> Visual Studio can't resolve Nuget dependencies after reinstalling
> operating system

It is quite strange and in my side, I can also build the project without any errors.(I download the project from your github link and then open it with VS0219----build well).

[image]

So I think your Net Core SDK or VS IDE have broken.

**1)**, please try to install the latest [Net Core 3.1 Developer SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

**Or** you could open **Programs and Features** from **Control Panel**, then right-click on every net core sdk-->**Change**-->**Repair**

**2)** run `sfc /scannow` to scan your os and you can refer to [this link for more steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

**3)**, try to [do a repair in VS Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019). Or if your VS2019 is not the latest, please update it to the latest version.

**4)** try to create a new net core project and then install these nuget packages to check if the issue still persists.

Comment: I attempted step 1 and it wanted to repair it. When I did it failed at: Applying execute package: aspnetcore_targeting_pack_3.1.3_win_x64.msi, action: Repair.

Comment: I recommended step 2 and it reportd "Verification 100% complete."

Comment: Or just repair from the vs_installer, it could also repair net core, did you the error persist?

Comment: Besides, you can also try to reset all settings from vs(`Tools`-->`Import and Export settings` -->`Reset all settings`). And did the issue persist?